# Does a primitive matrix have only real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

In the paper [Identification of Almost Invariant Aggregates in Reversible Nearly Uncoupled Markov Chains](http://publications.imp.fu-berlin.de/84/1/SC-98-03.pdf) it is stated that if $P$ is a reversible primitive stochastic matrix, then all its eigenvalues are in the interval $[-1,1]$.

First question: Shouldn't it be (more precisely) the interval $(-1,1]$ by the Perron-Frobenius theorem?

Second question: I don't understand the definition of being reversible for a matrix. It only makes sense together with a distribution vector. So we have to say the pair $(\pi,P)$ is reversible. But every primitive matrix has a stationary distribution such that $(\pi,P)$ is reversible. Does this mean that any primitive stochastic matrix has only real eigenvalues in the interval $(-1,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question: yes, you're right.  For some reason, the authors didn't feel the need to make the most precise statement possible.

To your second question: note that the condition for reversibility can only hold for a matrix and an **invariant** distribution vector, i.e. a distribution for which $\pi P = \pi$.  Notably, if $P$ is primitive, it has a *unique* invariant distribution.  So, I think that a primitive matrix is called "reversible" when its invariant distribution $\pi$ is such that $(\pi, P)$ is reversible.

I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that "every primitive matrix has a stationary distribution such that $(\pi,P)$ is reversible".

Comment: In the paper I posted, Lemma 2.2 contains the statement about real eigenvalues.

Comment: @user144921 okay, I see now.  But where did you get the idea that every primitive matrix has a stationary distribution such that $(\pi,P)$ is reversible?

Comment: @user144921 [here's an example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B.01,.98,.01%7D,%7B.01,.01,.98%7D,%7B.98,.01,.01%7D%7D) of a primitive matrix with complex numbers, which according to the paper means that there can be no distribution such that $(\pi, P)$ is reversible.

Comment: @user144921 notably, a markov chain (over finitely many states) is reversible if and only if it can be considered as a weighted random walk on a graph.

Comment: Ok thank you, I messed it up. If $(\pi,P)$ is reversible, then $\pi$ is stationary. The converse is not true. I don't know why I asked this stupid question. ;)

Comment: @user144921 well, there you go.  Glad to help.